# In search of a Better way for capturing frames from Gstreamer into a image container in glade

Tags: c++, linux, gstreamer, glade

i am seeking assistance in looking for a way to capture image frames from Gstreamer into a image container into glade form, at the present we are  using  cv::imshow(ImageFileName,MsgData->data.OpenCVImage);  but it is outside the Glade container Form,  how do we adjust this code to have it inside the glade form, any help would be great ,   thanks everyone..

```
  void writeframe(GtkMessageCustomData* MsgData)
 {
   std::chrono::seconds sec(1); // 3 seconds timeout

  using shakes = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1, 100000000>>;

// Arm the callback for saving an image into the cv::mat
MsgData->data.pImageEvent->reset();
MsgData->data.bImageReceived = false;
MsgData->data.snapImage = true;
    //////// Comes from Event.h /////////////////
    MsgData->data.pImageEvent->wait(shakes(sec));
    if( MsgData->data.bImageReceived )
  
      {
      // printf("Image received\n");
    
  // ##########  MsgData->data.ImageCount) ##################################
   // ##########  May possibly be going to MAT ###############################
   // ##### Need to transfer to an image Control through the Frames###########
    char ImageFileName[256];
    // orignal code for Saving of images
   //   sprintf(ImageFileName,"image%05d.jpg", MsgData->data.ImageCount);
     sprintf(ImageFileName,"image.jpg", MsgData->data.ImageCount);
    // cv::imwrite(ImageFileName,MsgData->data.OpenCVImage);
    cv::imshow(ImageFileName,MsgData->data.OpenCVImage);
    // printf("Put-Data-in\n");
    
}
else
{
    printf("whoops\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might be interested in [`gtkglsink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gtk/gtkglsink.html?gi-language=c) or [`gdkpixbufsink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gdkpixbuf/gdkpixbufsink.html?gi-language=c)

Comment: is there any possible way of helping me implement that into my code , to just actually show the image in a picturebox on a form using these methods .   thank you so much